# Rust lifetimes with trait

Tags: rust

Can someone help me understand why I'm getting the following error with this piece of code? I tried adding a lifetime to `name` but that didn't help either and I think I'm missing some fundamental principle here.

```
pub struct FullyConnected<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
    weights: Array3<f64>,
    biases: Array2<f64>,
}

impl<'a> Layer for FullyConnected<'a> {
    fn new(name:& str, in_dim: usize, out_dim: usize) -> Self {
        FullyConnected {
            name,
            weights: Array::random((1, in_dim, out_dim), StandardNormal),
            biases: Array::random((1, out_dim), StandardNormal),
        }
    }

    fn forward(&self, x: &Array3<f64>) -> Array3<f64> {
        Array::random(self.weights.raw_dim(), StandardNormal)
    }
    fn backward(&self, x: &Array3<f64>) -> Array3<f64> {
        Array::random(self.weights.raw_dim(), StandardNormal)
    }
}
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/bin/learn.rs:20:9
   |
20 |         FullyConnected {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined on the method body at 19:17...
  --> src/bin/learn.rs:19:17
   |
19 |     fn new(name:& str, in_dim: usize, out_dim: usize) -> Self {
   |                 ^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/bin/learn.rs:21:13
   |
21 |             name,
   |             ^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 18:6...
  --> src/bin/learn.rs:18:6
   |
18 | impl<'a> Layer for FullyConnected<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/bin/learn.rs:20:9
   |
20 | /         FullyConnected {
21 | |             name,
22 | |             weights: Array::random((1, in_dim, out_dim), StandardNormal),
23 | |             biases: Array::random((1, out_dim), StandardNormal),
24 | |         }
   | |_________^
   = note: expected `FullyConnected<'a>`
              found `FullyConnected<'_>`
```

Answer (score 2):

Your claim is that `FullyConnected` is *borrowing* a string belonging to someone else. Borrowing a string makes a lot of sense if you're a function, or even a temporary data structure that only exists for a short time. But it seems to me that your `struct` is meant to stand on its own and exist for some indeterminate amount of time. So you probably want `FullyConnected` to *own* a `String`, not borrow a `str`.

```
pub struct FullyConnected {
  name: String,
  ...
}
```

Your constructor can still take `&str` and clone it, if your use case is primarily passing constant strings.

```
fn new(name: &str, in_dim: usize, out_dim: usize) -> Self {
  FullyConnected {
    name: name.to_owned(),
    ...
  }
}
```

Or you can take a `String` and expect the caller to do the cloning. It depends on what your most common use case is.

For what it's worth, you can get your existing code (with the borrowed string) working by attaching the lifetime of the constructor argument to the lifetime of `Self`, so

```
fn new(name: &'a str, in_dim: usize, out_dim: usize) -> Self {
  ...
}
```

But this is, again, probably not what you want. It restricts users of this struct to having to store their strings somewhere and keep track of that themselves, which is probably less than ideal. Much easier to take the incredibly small performance hit of one string copy and have a simple, self-contained data structure that's easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your struct as containing a `&'a str` which is fine. But your new function doesn't enforce that `name` has the same lifetime. All `&` have a lifetime and if you let the compiler infer it, it will create a new one for you.

**The Problem**

```
impl<'a> Layer for FullyConnected<'a> {
    // 'b is created by the compiler
    fn new<'b>(name: &'b str) -> Self {
        FullyConnected { // FullyConnected <'a> wants 'a
            name, // name has lifetime 'b
        }
    }
}
```

To fix this you need to make sure `name` has a lifetime that is valid for use in `FullyConnected<'a>`. This is a case where giving an explicit lifetime is required. Giving `name` the lifetime `'a` will fix this.

**The Fix**

```
impl<'a> Layer for FullyConnected<'a> {
    // explicitly give name the lifetime 'a
    fn new(name: &'a str) -> Self {
        FullyConnected { // FullyConnected <'a> wants 'a
            name, // name has lifetime 'a
        }
    }
}
```